# Javafx ImageView real image position

Tags: java, image, javafx, imageview

I'm trying to realize a mouse over effect on a button.

What I have is a button with an ImageView in it. The ImageView displays a image in  shape of a triangle. So there are areas inside the ImageView in which no picture is displayed.

Can someone explain me how it's possible to only start the mouse over event when the mouse move over the actual image (not the blank areas).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say button do you mean the Button class?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html

Comment: Yes exactely :)

Comment: Would you consider forgoing the Button and just using the ImageView as the button?  Its really easy to do.

Comment: I think about it, but this doesn't solve the problem with the empty areas in the Imageview, right?

Comment: How are you actually doing what you're currently doing? I thought `pickOnBounds` was false by default for an `ImageView` anyway, so the `ImageView`'s `hoverProperty` should not change to true unless the mouse is over some non-transparent part of the image.

Comment: Okay now I tried it with the ImageView without the button. I used the "On Mouse Entered" event of the imageview, but it's already fired if the cursor move upon the blank areas

Comment: Oh okay "pickOnBound" property was true by default. Now it works. Thank you very much :)